# SOAP UI doesn't show response content correctly

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I am trying to use SOAP UI to test jms request, but the response content (in response panel) is the same the sent request, how can I fix this ? (I also try to add option "Add SoapAction as property" in JMS header, but not successful)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is not also reading the message from JMS again? As described here? https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html

Comment: @ophychius Thanks you. I used the same destination for sending and recieving (jms://SmartOTP_EMS::queue_vn.smartotp_gw.1.0::queue_vn.smartotp_gw.1.0) How can I config my request to get the response content in the response window

Comment: Jms itself does not send a response as such. You deliver the message and this delivery either fails or succeeds. If the application or service processing the jms message sends a response also using JMS it will use a response queue to which you can then listen for the applications' response